# Diffusion equation with boundary conditions

Tags: partial-differential-equations

I've been set this question, however I haven't seen one like this and I'm not sure what to do. Thanks for any answer.

Consider the diffusion equation:

$\frac{∂u}{∂t} - D\frac{∂^2u}{∂x^2} = f(x,t), x∈[0,L],t∈[0,∞] $

subject to periodic boundary conditions:

$u(0,t) = u(L,t),$
$u_x(0,t) = u_x(L,t).$

Prove that there exists a constant $C>0$ such that if $u_1(x,t)$ and $u_2(x,t) $ are solutions corresponding to the intitial conditions $φ_1(x) $ and $φ_2(x) $ respectively, then:

$$\int_0^L [u_1(x,t) - u_2(x,t)]^2 dx \leqslant C \int_0^L [φ_1(x) - φ_2(x)]^2 dx$$

for all $t \geqslant 0$.

Take care to indicate clearly where and how you proof uses the boundary conditions. What is the smallest value of C for which is inequality can be guaranteed.

Comment: Is this Your homework? What have You tried?

Comment: [See here.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2159469/lapunov-stability-of-diffusion-equation?rq=1)

Answer (score 3):

The question linked in the comments provided a method, but there wasn't a full answer. I'm writing one down here for reference.

First, set $v = u_1-u_2$. Since $u_1$ and $u_2$ both satisfy the same inhomogeneous equation, $v$ has to be a solution of the homogeneous equation (by linearity) and the same periodic B.C.s

\begin{cases} v_t - Dv_{xx} = 0 \\ v(0,t) = v(L,t) \\ v_x(0,t) = v_x(L,t) \\ v(x,0) = \varphi_1(x) - \varphi_2(x) = \psi(x) \end{cases}

Mutiplying the PDE by $v$ and integrating over $x\in(0,L)$

$$ \int_0^L v(x,t)v_t(x,t)\ dx = D\int_0^L v(x,t)v_{xx}(x,t)\ dx $$

Integration by parts on the RHS gives

$$ \int_0^L v(x,t)v_{xx}(x,t)\ dx = -\int_0^L (v_x(x,t))^2\ dx $$

Since $v(L,t)v_x(L,t) - v(0,t)v_x(0,t) = 0$ as per the B.C.s

The LHS is

$$ \int_0^L v(x,t)v_t(x,t)\ dx = \int_0^L \frac12 \frac{\partial}{\partial t}(v(x,t))^2 \ dx = \frac12 \frac{d}{dt} \left(\int_0^L (v(x,t))^2 \ dx\right) $$

by Leibniz's integral rule. Therefore

$$ \frac{d}{dt}\left(\int_0^L (v(x,t))^2\ dx\right) = -2D\int_0^L (v_x(x,t))^2 \ dx \le 0 $$

which means, if $g(t) = \int_0^L (v(x,t))^2 \ dx$ then $g(t)$ is non-increasing in $t \in (0,\infty)$. Hence, $g(t)$ attains its maximum at $t=0$, or

$$ \int_0^L (v(x,t))\ dx \le \int_0^L (v(x,0)^2\ dx = \int_0^L (\psi(x))^2 \ dx $$

Comment: Do you know how to work out 'what is the smallest value of C for which the inequality can be guaranteed' ?

Comment: @User19098 Read through my answer again. You should be able to figure out what $C$ is.

Comment: Apologies, my mistake.